# Micropython remove cr/lf on pico w

Tags: python, micropython

I'm pretty new to python and don't have a handle on the string functions yet.  I want to have a simple TCP server I can enter commands into and have the network part working, but I can't figure out something simple like removing the CR/LF at the end :)

Here's my simple code:

```py
request = str(cl.readline())
print("Line:")
print(request)
request = request.replace('\r', '')
print(request)
request = request.replace('\n', '')
print(request)
request = request.strip()
# this gives an error that decode doesn't exist
# request = request.decode('UTF-8')
#...
print("Unknown request:")
print(request)
```

But none of this seems to affect the string:

```
Line:
b'on\r\n'
b'on\r\n'
b'on\r\n'
Unknown request:
b'on\r\n'
```

I thought I might have to use `decode('UTF-8')`, but I get an attribute error with that saying it doesn't exist.

***Edit***

UGH!   Something I was doing was creating the string `"b'on\\r\\n'"`.  Is there a way to differentiate between these two using `print()`?

```py
s1 = b'on\r\n'
s2 = "b'on\r\n'"
print(s1)
print(s2)
```

Both show as `b'on\r\n'`.   I checked `len() and it was 9, but I assumed that was being unicode with a null terminator so that messed me up as well.

Comment: if you want to use string functions like `replace()`- convert your bytes to string, and use `mystring.replace('\\r', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Note the leading *b* - i.e., you have a bytes object. If you know that the bytes object always ends with b"\r\n" you can remove them using a slice.

e.g.,

```
b = b"abc\r\n"
b = b[:-2]
assert b == b"abc"
```

Comment: Rather than arbitrarily lopping off the last 2 bytes regardless of their content, wouldn't you do better with `b = b.strip()` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Not a good idea if you have (for example) b"abc \r\n" - i.e., some whitespace preceding b"\r\n"